# Big numbers: Ultrafactorials

Tags: code-golf, sequence, factorial

## Ultrafactorials

The ultrafactorials are a sequence of numbers which can be generated using the following function:

$$a(n) = n! ^ {n!}$$

The resulting values rise extremely quickly.
*Side note: This is entry [A046882](https://oeis.org/A046882) in the OEIS. Also related are the hyperfactorials, a still quite huge, but a bit smaller sequence: [A002109](https://oeis.org/A002109)*

## Your task

Your task is to implement these numbers into your language. Your program will calculate the **sum of all ultrafactorials** from 0 up to *inclusive* `n`.

### Input

Your program may only take one input: a number, which resembles the last \$a(n)\$ ultrafactorial to be added to the sum. The Input is assured to be positive or 0.

### Output

Your output is all up to you, as long as there's the visible sum of the numbers somewhere.

### Rules

- You can assume all integers, therefore integer input, and using integer counting loops to produce some results.

### Test cases

```
Input: -1
Output: Any kind of error (because -1! is undefined), or no handling at all

Input: 0
Output: 1

Input: 1
Output: 2

Input: 2
Output: 6

Input: 3
Output: 46662
```

## Challenge

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the answer with the least length in bytes wins!

Comment: Do we need to consider arbitrarily large integers? Or is it enough to handle the largest that the language's default data type (such as `double`) supports ?

Comment: The conversion in-code and output is up to you, the Input will be an integer though. @LuisMendo

Comment: Changing the rules after many people have answered isn't a nice thing to do either. Please use the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) as advised whenever you want to submit a challenge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

Code:

```
Ý!DmO
```

Explanation:

```
Ý       # Take the range [0, ..., input]
 !      # Map factorial over each element
  Dm    # Exponentiate each element to itself
    O   # Take the sum
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w50hRG1P&input=Mw)

Comment: `L!DmO` also works if you want to take off the "CP-1252 encoding" bit.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn No it doesn't. `L!DmO>` would, but returns \$3\$ for \$0\$, so it's invalid.

Answer (score 17):

## Mathematica, 19 bytes

```
Sum[n!^n!,{n,0,#}]&
```

Apologies for the extremely clear code  ;)

Comment: Using mathematica for mathematica - dick move :D

Answer (score 8):

## Jelly, 6 bytes

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCY4bi2ISpgUw&input=&args=Mw)

```
‘Ḷ!*`S // Main link: Argument n (integer)
‘      // Take n, increment by 1
 Ḷ     // Range from [0..n]
  !    // Calculates factorial for each [0..n]
   *`  // Raises each [0!..n!] to the power of itself
     S // Sum the resulting array
```

Comment: There is an increment atom, `‘`, so ``R!*`S‘`` saves a byte (I went for ``‘Ḷ!*`S``).

Comment: I actually was in the middle of editing before I saw your comment :P

Comment: I saw that too, good job.

Comment: [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///obkWthOD///8bAwA)

Answer (score 7):

### R -  <s>34</s>  30 bytes

```
x=factorial(0:scan());sum(x^x)
```

vectorizing is nice

**edit:** saved 4 bytes thanks to @MickyT

Comment: you can shortened it a bit by moving you scan into the factorial `x=factorial(0:scan());sum(x^x)`

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), <s>41</s> <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```
{[+] ([**] [*](1..$_)xx 2 for 0..$_)}
```

```
{[+] ([**] ([*] 1..$_)xx 2 for 0..$_)}
```

```
{sum (($_**$_ with [*] 1..$_) for 0..$_)}
```

([Try it online.](https://tio.run/#h2mY0))

#### Explanation:

- `for 0 .. $_`: For each integer from 0 to the input,
- `[*](1 .. $_) xx 2`: calculate the factorial twice,
- `[**] ...`: and exponentiate the two identical factorials.
- `[+] ...`: Then sum all results of the loop.

*Thanks to b2gills for 1 byte.*

Comment: `([*] …)` can be written as `[*](…)` saving a byte

Answer (score 4):

## J, <s>15</s> 12 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to miles!

```
1#.i.^~@!@,]
```

### Explanation

```
1#.i.^~@!@,]  input: y
          ,]  append y to list...
   i.         [0, y)
        !@    factorial each member
     ^~@      raise each to itself
1#.           perform summation
```

### Test cases

```
   f =: 1#.i.^~@!@,]
   (,. f"0) i.4
0     1
1     2
2     6
3 46662
   (,. f"0) i.6
0           1
1           2
2           6
3       46662
4  1.33374e33
5 3.17504e249

   echo"1] _90]\":f 6x
190281878633201797429473437859705759836595323046380462211756876146775419721154680216391116
383660154937824558291984804764687140715927099993629348072943551413397410741069111169123658
220861477766905534108349401724389611558474171816216027733366046875815097164882588181826712
426524007417126023680300953790645455254723360874298622143752208989152655091222094594342956
890526202094068774356589887610542642450567071133028553816930267473112879050178461179814798
008667622200592591542432361632955904924276854403585221477449385731481108378608652069211835
448555831555820393949831627809528917004144455150642180845929102272754394116905511650997561
389917179995442329297103257850695109383021080317204810134810158543814178231002423431556657
737982683316707709406053569620116083909440177269311235173671447595521339849978144493268530
780365729831790064477684808893338190825461650933123545889305523546630119181308584140916288
912561260392366609493077363059677222110731132927863243720195975705161197786520981159422881
575250362836779593393897664990291828935858671453835924398316498051705698128484688847592380
831018330553151156822298060174230201841578757499203145955456593022852288527824268115043999
037373974753999860179933517198889966353093307592136928730661270863274130109304971274296438
682725017433937245229524959283895094220677649257613358344409711070780405579776000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000003175042373780336892901667920556557182493442088021222004926225128381629943118937129
098831435345716937405655305190657814877412786176000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001333735776850284124449081472890438
```

Comment: `1#.i.^~@!@,]` shaves a few more bytes off.

Comment: @miles Oh, cool. I didn't know `1#.` performs summation. If that's not a tip already, you should definitely add it!

Answer (score 3):

## [Cheddar](http://cheddar.vihan.org), <s>44</s> 37 bytes

```
n->(0|>n=>(i,a=(1|>i)/(*))->a**a)/(+)
```

Thank goats for reduce operator! I think it would've been good idea to add factorial

[Try it online](http://vihan.org/p/tio/?l=cheddar&p=y0ktUUizVcjTtdMwqLHLs7XTyNRJtNUwrLHL1NTX0NLU1LVL1NJKBLK1Na25uAqKMvOAGjSMgRwY20TT@j8A)

### Ungolfed

```
n -> ( 0|>n => (i, a=(1|>i) / (*)) -> a ** a) / (+)
```

### Explanation

**Note:** A little outdated, will fix

```
n ->           // Input
( 0 |> n) =>   // Run below for each of [0, n]
    (              
      i,           // Input
      a =          // Let's keep n! in this variable `a`
         (1 |> i)  // Range from [1, n]
         / (*)     // Multiply all the items of that range
                   // `/` is reduce `(*)` is multiplication function
    ) ->
    a ** a         // A to the power of A
) / (+)        // Sum all results
```

Comment: Isn't *thank god* a little bit presumptuous here? :D

Comment: @flawr ok. Fixed :P

Comment: Haha, better, perhaps one of the few legit usages of *goat* we've seen around here recenly :)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
Q:Ygt^s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@x9oFZleElf8/78xAA)

#### Explanation

```
Q         % Take input n implicitly. Add 1
 :        % Range [1 2 ... n+1]
  Yg      % Gamma function, element-wise. This gives [0! 1! ... n!]
    t^    % Rise result to itself, element-wise
      s   % Sum all values. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <del>64</del> 66 bytes

```
->n{(o=(1..n).map{|i|a=(1..i).inject(:*);a**a}.inject(:+))?o+1:1}
```

Added two characters for the off-by-one bugfix (will look into shortening the inject calls later).

Comment: I'm not good with Ruby but couldn't you fix this with `a=(0..i)` instead of `a=(1..i)`?

Comment: @Timtech Expect injecting zero into a multiplication doesn't do anyone any good :(

Comment: Right, I guess adding `+1` is the best solution.

Comment: @GB Applied trivial fix for n=0 case.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 49 bytes

```php
for($f=1;$i<=$argv[1];$f*=++$i)$s+=$f**$f;echo$s;
```

`INF` for `n>5` on a 64 bit system.

**for large numbers, 70 bytes**

```
while($i<=$argv[1])$s=gmp_add($s,gmp_pow($f=gmp_fac($i++),$f));echo$s;
```

requires PHP to be compiled with `--with-gmp`

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>67</s> 56 bytes

Note that this submission was made *before* the rules that banned builtins were removed.

```
p=product
a n=sum[p[x|x<-[p[1..i]],_<-[1..x]]|i<-[0..n]]
```

For example:

```
*Main> a 0
1
*Main> a 1
2
*Main> a 2
6
*Main> a 3
46662
*Main> a 4
1333735776850284124449081472890438
*Main> a 5
3175042373780336892901667920556557182493442088021222004926225128381629943118937129098831435345716937405655305190657814877412786176000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001333735776850284124449081472890438
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
s^Rd.!Mh
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%5ERd.%21Mh&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3&debug=0).

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES7), 38 bytes

```
f=(n,a=1,i=0)=>i>n?0:a**a+f(n,a*++i,i)
```

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk Sorry, force of habit.

Answer (score 2):

## R, 42 <s>35</s> bytes

Now that I've read the question properly, I've put the sum in.

This requires the **gmp** (multiple precision arithmetic) library to be available.  This allows for large numbers to be handled.  Otherwise anything over 5 returns `INF`.

This is implemented as a unnamed function to avoid the `as.character` that would be required to output to STDOUT through `cat`

```
function(x)sum((i=gmp::factorialZ(0:x))^i)
```

Example run

```
> f <- function(x)sum((i=gmp::factorialZ(0:x))^i)
> f(5)
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 3175042373780336892901667920556557182493442088021222004926225128381629943118937129098831435345716937405655305190657814877412786176000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001333735776850284124449081472890438
> f(6)
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 190281878633201797429473437859705759836595323046380462211756876146775419721154680216391116383660154937824558291984804764687140715927099993629348072943551413397410741069111169123658220861477766905534108349401724389611558474171816216027733366046875815097164882588181826712426524007417126023680300953790645455254723360874298622143752208989152655091222094594342956890526202094068774356589887610542642450567071133028553816930267473112879050178461179814798008667622200592591542432361632955904924276854403585221477449385731481108378608652069211835448555831555820393949831627809528917004144455150642180845929102272754394116905511650997561389917179995442329297103257850695109383021080317204810134810158543814178231002423431556657737982683316707709406053569620116083909440177269311235173671447595521339849978144493268530780365729831790064477684808893338190825461650933123545889305523546630119181308584140916288912561260392366609493077363059677222110731132927863243720195975705161197786520981159422881575250362836779593393897664990291828935858671453835924398316498051705698128484688847592380831018330553151156822298060174230201841578757499203145955456593022852288527824268115043999037373974753999860179933517198889966353093307592136928730661270863274130109304971274296438682725017433937245229524959283895094220677649257613358344409711070780405579776000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003175042373780336892901667920556557182493442088021222004926225128381629943118937129098831435345716937405655305190657814877412786176000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001333735776850284124449081472890438
```

f(9) will runs pretty well, but fills up a number of pages.  A few hundred or so and 2,017,528 digits.  f(10) kills the session on my machine.

Comment: I think the reason its different than the other answers is because you're supposed to return the sum from 0!^0! to N!^N!. But this is easy to amend by changing to `factorialZ(0:x)`. Is there a specific reason to not use the `base::factorial()` function?

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam Thanks for the catch.  Need to read the questions better :).  I'm using `gmp::factorialZ` to handle the big numbers.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>73</s> 72 bytes

```
import math
lambda n,f=math.factorial:sum(f(i)**f(i)for i in range(n+1))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 19 bytes

```
n->sum(k=0,n,k!^k!)
```

Comment: Was just about to post this. Glad I checked first.

Answer (score 2):

## GameMaker Language, 97 bytes

Main function (52 bytes)

```
for(a=0;a<=argument0;a++)b+=power(f(a),f(a))return b
```

Function f (45 bytes)

```
a=argument0 if!a return 1else return a*f(a--)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Dyalog APL, 10 bytes

```
(+/!*!)0,⍳
```

**How?**

`⍳` range of input

`0,` preceded with 0

`!*!` apply `x! ^ x!`

`+/` sum

Comment: `*` and `!` are scalar functions, so use arrays: `+/*⍨!0,⍳⎕` or `(+/!*!)0,⍳` if you really want a train.

Answer (score 2):

## [Golfscript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/index.html), 41 bytes

```
{.{,{1+}%{*}*}{;1}if}:f;~.,\+{.f\f?}%{+}*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v1qvWqfaULtWtVqrVqu22tqwNjOt1irNuk5PJ0a7Wi8tJs0eKKddq/X/vzEA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `+`, \$ 7 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 5.76 bytes

```
RFDz.^S
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSStlLsgqWlJWm6FsuD3Fyq9OKCITyo4IKFxhAGAA)

##### Explanation

```python
RFDz.^S  # implicit input
         # + flag adds one
R        # range from 0
 F       # factorial of each
   z.    # for each number:
  D  ^   #  raise it to the power of itself
      S  # sum the resulting list
         # implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [vemf](https://github.com/selaere/vemf), <s>3</s> 5 bytes

```
▲↕!┴^
```

### Explanation

```
▲↕    ' range [0, α)
   ┴  ' run this function:
    ^ '   exponentation
      ' with this for both inputs:
  !   '   factorial of each element in range
```

e.g. `3▲↕!┴^+` – [try it online](https://selaere.github.io/vemf/wasm/index.html?code=Mx4SIcFeKw)

Comment: Nice language!  Note though that you need to sum the ultrafactorals from 0..n, not just return the ultrafactorial of n.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen oops! fixed

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 19 bytes

```
Sum[a!^a!,{a,0,#}]&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a number as input, and returns a number as output.

Comment: We can't use factorial or exponentiation builtin.

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 11 bytes

```
hFSBD]1*B)s
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=hFSBD%5D1%2aB%29s&input=3)

```
hF          -  for i in range (0, input+1)
  SB        -     product(range(1, i+1)
    D]1*    -    [^]*^
        B   -   product(^)
          s - sum(^)
```

Fun fact: Pyke doesn't have a factorial built-in because `SB` is only 2 bytes!

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 43 bytes

```
b n|f<-product[1..n]=f^f
a n=sum$b<$>[0..n]
```

Usage example: `a 3`-> `46662`.

`b` calculates a single ultrafactorial and `a` sums all ultrafactorials from `0` to `n`.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES7), 44 bytes

```
g=n=>n?(f=a=>a?a*f(a-1):1)(n)**f(n)+g(n-1):1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 82 Bytes

```
x=input()
s=0
for z in range(x):
 t=1
 for i in range(z+1):t*=i+1
 s+=t**t
print s
```

Comment: Have you tried summing a list comprehension?

Comment: You've only used x once, so you could use `range(input())` this would remove a few bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Wonder](https://github.com/wonderlang/wonder), 33 bytes

```
@sum(->@^ f\prod rng1#0f)rng0+1#0
```

Usage:

```
(@sum(->@^ f\prod rng1#0f)rng0+1#0)3
```

## Explanation

```
rng0+1#0
```

Create inclusive range from 0 to input.

```
->@^ f\prod rng1#0f
```

Map over the range with a function that 1) calculates the factorial of the item, 2) stores the result to `f`, and 3) calculates `f^f`.

```
sum
```

Sum.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 13 bytes

```
sum(seq(A!^A!,A,0,Ans
```

P.S. You can replace `sum(seq(` with `Σ(` if you have a newer operating system (no size change).

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby 2, 41 bytes

```
->n{(1..n).reduce(s=1){|t,i|t+(s*=i)**s}}
```

Comment: Awesome!  Very clever the way it initializes `s` at the same time as passing it as the initial `t` value to reduce/inject.

Comment: Can be golfed one more character to `->n{((t=s=1)..n).map{|i|t+=(s*=i)**s};t}` or `->n{t=s=1;(1..n).map{|i|t+=(s*=i)**s};t}`

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
→ṁo´^Πḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9odXNr/yBt4oKB/@KGkuG5gW/CtF7OoOG4o////1swLDEsMiwzLDQsNSw2LDdd)

```
→          One plus
 ṁ         the sum of
     Π     x!
    ^      to the power of
   ´       itself
 ṁo        for each x in
      ḣ    the range from 1 to
           the input.
```

It would be slightly more correct to use [`ṁo´^ΠΘḣ`](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9odXNr/yBt4oKB/@G5gW/CtF7OoM6Y4bij////WzAsMSwyLDMsNCw1LDYsN10), actually adding 0 into the range, but since 0!^0!=1^1=1, this works too.

Answer (score 1):

## [Whispers v3](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), <sup><s>77</s></sup> 69 bytes

```
> Input
> 0
>> L!
>> … 2 1 3
>> L*L
>> Each 5 4
>> ∑6
>> Output 7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsEzr6C0hMtOwYDLzk7BRxFEPmpYpmCkYKhgDBbS8gFRronJGQqmCiZg@Y6JZiDav7QEqFfB/P9/YwA)

Yet another 69 byte answer thanks to Leo.

Comment: Using `…` instead of the first `Each` is shorter: https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsEzr6C0hMtOwYDLzk7BRxFEPmpYpmCkYKhgDBbS8gFRronJGQqmCiZg@Y6JZiDav7QEqFfB/P9/YwA

Comment: That's new to me as well..

Comment: The documentation for Whispers v3 is still incomplete, but [the tutorial for Whispers v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers/blob/v2/tutorial.md) has a complete list of "command lines", all still usable

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 5 bytes

```
ř!ṖƩ⁺
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//6EzFhzunHVv5qHHX///GAA)

```
ř           implicit input; řangify
 !          factorial
  Ṗ         raise n to the nth Ṗower
   Ʃ        Ʃum
    ⁺       increment
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 5.5 bytes

```
+~+.,$^;`*,
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWq7XrtPV0VOKsE7R0ICJQiQXLDbgMuYy4jCFcAA)

*-0.5 byte thanks to Dominic van Essen*

```
+~+.,$^;`*,
+~          Add 1
  +         to the sum
   .        for each n in
    ,       range from 1 to
     $      input
        `*  of the product of
          , range from 1 to
            n
      ^     to the power of
       ;    itself
```

Comment: [5.5 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWq7XrtPV0VOKsE7R0ICJQiQXLDbgMuYy4jCFcAA)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I'm dumb… Thanks!

Comment: Correction: 11 bytes -> 5.5 bytes

Comment: Argh… ATO still can't handle the byte counts properly…

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 4 bytes

```
ʀ¡:e
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzQSIsIiIsIsqAwqE6ZSIsIiIsIi0xXG4wXG4xXG4yXG4zIl0=)

```
ʀ  range [0, input]
¡  factorial (vectorizes)
:  duplicate list
e  exponentiate
s  sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 29 bytes

```arturo
$=>[∑map..0&=>[^<=∏1..&]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?hN1cQ8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Ç╔Ñst(jÖ3l
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=80c9a57374286a99336c&i=-1%0A0%0A1%0A2%0A3&m=2)

This is PackedStax, which unpacks to the following 11 bytes:

```
R{|Fc#}m|+^
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=R%7B%7CFc%23%7Dm%7C%2B%5E&i=-1%0A0%0A1%0A2%0A3&m=2)

```
R{    }m    # map over range 1..input
  |F        # push n!
    c       # dup
     #      # exponentiate
        |+  # sum
          ^ # increment (deals with 0 case)
```

Answer (score 1):

## C (gcc), <s>71</s> 70 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @ceilingcat!

```c
i,j,k;a(n){for(j=0;~n;--n,j+=pow(i,i))for(i=k=1;n/++k;)i*=k;return j;}
```

You can test it online [here](https://onlinegdb.com/jGDWHgTSo) ([Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##RY7NCsIwEITvfYqlUNiYFCse17yJl5Ba2QS3JVQ9lPrqMQV/5jKH@T4Y3169z5lNMJEcilqGMWGwHb2E2lZM0HYan8iGldomttEeSPZaR1K8s5HSZb4ngUBrZpnh5ljwMXKvqqWCT4oJuK0MFjoqdbJwJNCaFfyxb6ZU2AFrh02vitH0Z6kNsAGH5Qf9hLVa8xs) seems to lack the `pow` function).

<s>88</s> 87-byte solution without builtins:

```c
i,j,k,e;a(n){for(j=0;~n;--n,j+=e){for(i=k=1;n/++k;)i*=k;for(e=k=i;--k;)e*=i;}return j;}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##RYvLCsIwEEX3/YqhUEhMihWXY/7ETWhTmRSnEqqbEn89TvF1NzOce0/fXvq@FLLRTjagV6zXcU4qug6fjG3LNhoX3pDc5A7Ie2Mm1LRzE240CCVZCgs7@XIKyz0xRMyFeIGrJ1aPmQZdrRV8IiKorSVw0KGck4MjgjGk4T/75pZkO6raq2bQYjTDmWsLZMEr0hp/Qq5yeQE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 70 bytes

```python
import math
x=lambda n,f=math.factorial:1if n==0else f(n)**f(n)+x(n-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBDgIhDEDRtZyiyzKOxomuJuEwVanTBAqpLPD0GDZ/8fLrrx1F72NIrsUaZGqH6yFRfr4JdOUw5cr0asWE0r4Jg4Zwi@kbgVH9ssyeO@pl84OLgYAoGOkn4sPv7lRNtKGs0FG8dx3n@Ac)

Comment: [67](https://tio.run/##FcgxDsIwDAXQnVN4tEtBqmCq1MMYSqil5ieyPKSnD3R5w6tHbAWP3i3X4kFZY7u0Zdf8WpUwpuWce9J3FDfdZ5BipcSQYTi9NsZtkuI09fTXyECu@H74KXN1Q7CN1NhE@g8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ĖwD*
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNCU5NndEKiZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTMmZmxhZ3M9Uw==)

##### Explanation

```python
ĖwD*  # Implicit input
Ė     # Push [0..input]
 w    # Factorial of each
  D*  # To the power of itself
      # Implicit output of sum
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 12 bytes

```
y:{$!F:F^}a+
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=eTp7JCFGOkZefWEr&input=NQ&args=Wg)

#### Explanation

```
y                 The list [0, ..., Input]
 :{      }a       Apply the predicate below to each element of that list
           +      The output is the sum of the results

   $!F              F is the factorial of the input
      :F^           Output = F^F
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 79 bytes with console output

```
n=>{int i=1,j=1;for(;i<=n;i++)j*=i;System.Console.Write(System.Math.Pow(j,j));}
```

## C#, 64 bytes as a return

```
n=>{int i=1,j=1;for(;i<=n;i++)j*=i;return System.Math.Pow(j,j);}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Actually <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
1+r`!;ⁿ`MΣ
```

**How it works**

```
Program takes implicit input, implicit print at EOF
1+          Add one to the input n+1
  r         Create a range (0,1,..,n)
   `   `    Create a function between the two `
    !       Factorialize the current stack item
     ;      Duplicate the current stack item
      ⁿ     Power a,b from the current stack item
         M  Map the function across the stack top item
          Σ Sum the stack together
```

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 54 bytes

```
(for/sum((i(+ 1 n)))(let((t(factorial i)))(expt t t)))
```

Ungolfed:

```
#lang racket
(require math)

(define (f n)
  (for/sum ((i (+ 1 n)))
    (let ((t (factorial i)))
      (expt t t))))
```

Testing:

```
(f -1)
(f 0)
(f 1)
(f 2)
(f 3)
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
6
46662
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
òÊx_pZ
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=8sp4X3Ba&input=Mw==)

---

### Explantion

Implicit input of integer `U`
`3`

```
ò
```

Create an array of integers from 0 to `U`, inclusive.
`[0,1,2,3]`

```
Ê
```

Get the factorial of each integer in the array.
`[1,1,2,6]`

```
_
```

Map over the array.

```
pZ
```

Raise each element (`p`) to the power of itself (`Z`).
`[1,1,4,46656]`

```
x
```

Reduce by addition and implicitly output the result.
`46662`

Comment: In 2023, this is 5 bytes `òÊ®pZ` `-x`, or if the range was exclusive it would be 4 `ÊpUÊ` `-mx`

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 11 bytes

```apl
+/(*⍨∘!0,⍳)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/TeFR2wQFbX0NrUe9Kx51zFA00HnUu1mT61HfVKBEGpAihfn/vwGXIZcRlzGXCQA)

---

This function train is equivalent to `{+/*⍨!0,⍳⍵}`, which is a straight forward implementation

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 38 bytes

```perl6
{[+] map {my \a=[*] 1..$_;a**a},0..$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZm@786WjtWITexQKEaKBCTaButFatgqKenEm@dqKWVWKtjAGLX/rfmKk6sVEhTUIlXSMsvUrAxUDBUMFIwVjCxs/4PAA)

Comment: [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZm@7/aUDtaO1YhN7FAoVolXktLJb5WJzpGK1bBUE8PyP5vzVWcWKmQpqASr5CWX6RgY6BgqGCkYKxgYmf9HwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
ƒN!N!m}O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//2CQ/RT/F3Fr///@NAQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.factorials math.unicode`, 29 bytes

```
[ [0,b] [ n! dup ^ ] map Σ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYw7DsIwEER7TjH0KAqfCg6AaGgQlRUk42zASrI29rpAiNNwH65kAqR7o3kzjTbiQj4edvvtGi0Fpg69lmsRNF8o/rn5WVZ3Y05sjatpLBMbsY4jIt0SsRlWPpDI3QfLgs3kgRJzLLDECs@soMrZuYICT1EnjxOq4cnj/UKVvxBFm7bIHw)

```
  [0,b]                      ! range from 0 to input inclusive
        [          ] map     ! map over each element in the range
          n!                 ! factorial
             dup ^           ! raised to itself
                         Σ   ! sum
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, <s>129</s> 106 bytes

```swift
import Darwin
var s={(0...$0).map{let x=Double($0<1 ?1:(1...$0).reduce(1,*))
return pow(x,x)}.reduce(0,+)}
```

Fatal-errors on `n < 0`, `inf` for `n >= 6`. Probably macOS-only due to needing to `import Darwin` to access the `pow(_:_:)` function. (Using `Darwin` instead of `Foundation` saved both 4 bytes and my sanity.)

When implementing the factorial, I had to hard-code the value for `0` in order to bypass `Fatal error: Range requires lowerBound <= upperBound`.

There's a space to the left of the `?` due to `1` not being optional. We don't need the space to the right.